# can't locate node [ORB_SLAM] in package [ORB_SLAM]

Tags: ros, slam-algorithm

While running this launch file,

```
<launch>

   <node pkg="rqt_image_view" type="rqt_image_view" name="rqt_image_view" respawn="false" output="log">
        <remap from="/image" to="/ORB_SLAM/Frame" />
        <param name="autosize" value="true"/>
        </node>

        <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find ORB_SLAM)/Data/rviz.rviz" output="log">
   </node>

        <node pkg="ORB_SLAM" type="ORB_SLAM" name="ORB_SLAM"  args="Data/ORBvoc.yml Data/Settings.yaml" cwd="node" output="screen">
   </node>

</launch>
```

I am getting the following error,

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ORB_SLAM/ORB_SLAM]: can't locate node [ORB_SLAM] in package [ORB_SLAM]
```

how to fix this issue ?

where is the problem here ? how should my package structure be ?

I have created a ros package using catkin_creake_pkg with the name ORB_SLAM, yet I am getting the same error.

Can anyone help to fix this ?

Comment: People seem to have encountered this problem before but the causes were diverse. Google for "cannot launch node of type [ORB_SLAM/ORB_SLAM]" and see if any of their problems are similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

i think the reason maybe that you havn't add the path of ORBSLAM to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, therefore system can't locate the node orbslam

you should:

1. run the command in shell:

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="{path of orbslam in you computer}:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}

2. you can also write that command to the file ~/.bashrc, them reopen the shell, by doing that everytime you open the shell, the script will run automatically